# Need help troubleshooting a lighting change in EEVEE from an unknown source

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have an animation that I'm working on and mid scene there is a lighting change that happens which brightens the scene.

I think it is the sun lamp that I have in the scene because when I disable it the lighting stays consistent.  I have narrowed down the exact frame where it happens but there are no keyframes tied to any lighting elements that would change the lighting in the scene. I have deleted the sun lamp and added a new one, same problem.

I copied a sun lamp from the next scene where there are no issues and as soon as its pasted into the scene I get the same lighting change at the same frame.  I need the lighting so match the next scene perfectly so its seamless when edited together and have put a lot of time into it so far and don't want to have to recreate any lighting changes in the following scenes.

What am I not seeing/checking?

You don't see the lighting change when looking at the scene through the full viewport. It is only seen when looking through the camera or once rendering frames.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine the situation by your description. Attached images or videos could help, and best of all, the blend file.

Comment: You can upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/